# LUIS Azure DevOps pipeline, how to create any samples?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-language-understanding, azure-devops-rest-api

There is a requirement, to create Azure Devops pipeline which could support version, add file into application, train, test & publish application into Stage & production.

How it can be done through Azure Devops Pipeline. Any documentation or steps could be helpful.

Thanks
A.Prabhuram

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar through Azure CLI (PowerShell version 2.X) tasks, but it is not straight forward. I haven't done all of the steps as you mention above, but hopefully this will give you what you need to further build on it.

As a baseline, the functions you need are outlined in the [LUIS Programmatic API](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f). You will need the LUIS key and app id for most requests, which you can get via

```bsh
$LUISKEY= & az cognitiveservices account keys list -g "resourceGroupName" --name "LUISauthoringKeyName" --query key1 -o tsv

$header = @{"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"="$LUISKEY"}

$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/authoring/v3.0-preview/apps/?take=1" -Method 'Get' -Headers $header

$appid = $res.id
```

For brevity, I'm not repeating this code. But if you have separate tasks and/or agent jobs in your pipeline (as opposed to doing this as one script, which I do not recommend), you'll need to repeat these statements for each task. Do take note of the region and modify as needed for your authoring resource.

Obviously, to update your LUIS version, you need to have the model definition. I don't do this often since we are set up to use the same LUIS app in QA and PROD. So I just add a new version to the project repo if I need to run it through DevOps. Then I add the repo as an artifact for the release pipeline. But you should be able to use the [Export Application Version API](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40) to get it programmatically, though I haven't tried personally. Here is what I did to add the new version:

```bsh
$body = Get-Content '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AveryCreek_OEM_CSC_Bot/models/luis/AveryCreek OEM_CSC Team.json' | Out-String

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/authoring/v3.0-preview/apps/$appid/versions/import" -Method 'Post' -Body $body -Headers $header
```

Note that this version is not additive and **will completely replace your previous version** (though you can revert). In other words, if you have changes to the previous version that are NOT incorporated into the version you are importing, they will be lost. This is one of the main reasons we do not use separate LUIS apps per environment (sidebar - you can use separate *predicition* resources so you don't use production capacity while testing, but all of the endpoint utterances still go through to the one application).

Once the version is imported, you need to train and publish it. I personally don't have any testing built in, but I'm sure you could build some calls via the [LUIS Prediction API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78) and check for expected results. To train, you first need to grab the version, then call the training endpoint.

```bsh
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/authoring/v3.0-preview/apps/$appid/versions" -Method 'Get' -Headers $header

$version = $res[0].version

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/authoring/v3.0-preview/apps/$appid/versions/$version/train" -Method 'Post' -Headers $header
```

The next part is the most tricky. You can't publish the app until it is done training. To mitigate the risk of trying to publish before it is ready, I have created a separate agent job in my "Train and Publish" task to delay it.

[image: Agent jobs for Train and Publish]

This is typically enough delay, but I also have a check on training status and throw an error if it is not ready. Here is the snippet to get and check status and then publish.

```bsh
$status = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/authoring/v3.0-preview/apps/$appid/versions/$version/train" -Method 'Get' -Headers $header

if ($status.details[0].status -ne "Success" -and $status.details[0].status -ne "UpToDate") { throw }

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/authoring/v3.0-preview/apps/$appid/publish" -Method 'Post' -Body $body -Headers $header
```

And that should do it! As I mentioned, take care to make sure you define things like the LUIS Key and App ID in each task, as I have not repeated all of those values here. And you can add additional tasks to programmatically export the version (make sure you get the right key for your source app) and test the model as desired.